# using a pointer to a struct inside a class

Tags: c++

I am using an external C library (libsvm) from within C++. I insert the header file in my class header file using

```
extern "C"{
#include "svm.h"
}
```

This library contains a struct called svm_model. It also contains a function that given some input parameters it allocates (malloc) space for a struct svm_model and returns a pointer to it. The function is

```
svm_model *svm_train(input_parameters)
```

In my code (in C++) I create a variable in my class that is a struct svm_model pointer. In my header file I do

```
class myClass
{
public:
  int do_something();
private:
  struct svm_model *m_data;
}
```

Inside "do_something()" I have successfully called svm_train in the following way:

```
struct svm_model *test = svm_train(input_parameters);
```

But whenever I want to write the result into m_data, I get a segmentation_fault. This happens for

```
m_data = svm_train(input_parameters);
```

but also happens if I do

```
struct svm_model *test = svm_train(input_parameters);
m_data = test;
```

In fact, I noticed that even if I do

```
printf("hello: %p\n", m_data);
```

It also crashes. Therefore I suspect that there has to be a problem with using a pointer to a structure (which has been defined elsewhere) inside a class, although I have not found any hints anywhere. I tried initializing it to NULL in my class constructor, but does not change anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the function you use allocates memory?

Comment: Could you perhaps create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is but this 'Therefore I suspect that there has to be a problem with using a pointer to a structure (which has been defined elsewhere) inside a class,' is wrong. C++ would be pretty useless if true.

Comment: Guessing I would say there is something wrong with the way you are creating or using myClass objects. But until we see some more code it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just found the problem and it was indeed elsewhere than reported.
What happened is that I had created an STL vector of myClass and was accessing the methods on the first element of such vector, even though I had not explicitly created it, i.e.:

```
std::vector<myClass> dummy;
dummy[0].do_something();
```

Given that everything was compiling properly I did not think that this part of the code could give a problem.

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 6):

If it crashes with simply

```
  printf ("hello: %p\n", (void*)m_data);
```

then probably the issue is elsewhere and before. It looks like when you call that `printf` function `this` is invalid (perhaps `NULL` ?) or your memory heap is in very bad shape.

On Linux, I would suggest to compile with `g++ -Wall -g` with a recent compiler (GCC 4.8 has just been released). Improve the code till no warnings are given. Then use `gdb` and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to debug it more.

You might want to also compile your `libsvm` with debugging information and all warnings (or simply, use the debug variant of that package).

Answer (score 1):

The file svm.h already has the

```
extern "C" {
```

declaration. So instead of:

```
extern "C"{
#include "svm.h"
}
```

simply do:

```
#include "svm.h"
```

Also there is no need to repeat the struct key word again and again. So instead of:

```
struct svm_model *m_data;
```

do:

```
svm_model *m_data;
```

Comment: This is true, but that won't help about the bug. Your proposal is purely syntactical (but still useful for readability reasons). It should not change significantly the compiler generated code.